# Anaconda crashes when I attempt to use certain Numpy, Scipy, or Matplotlib functions

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I receive an error when I try to run some functions on Anaconda (specifically the Jupyter Notebook). For example, when I attempt to use linalg from Numpy, I receive the following error and the kernel crashes:

> The procedure entry point mkl_aa_fw_init_workdivision could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\myusername\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll

The file *mkl_intel_thread.dll* is located in the directory, so I'm not sure what this error exactly means. The same error is displayed when I run other functions from Scipy or Matplotlib. Some functions like the *dot* function in Numpy work, but some others don't.

For further reference, the message on the command prompt reads:

> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll
>
> [I 16:38:02.361 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5)

Any help resolving this issue would be thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: Someone seems to have experienced the same problem: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6923

Comment: Thanks, the thread you linked me too solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found that uninstalling Amplitube fixed the problem. This was one of the solutions proposed in this link provided by jp_data_analysis: [Click Here](http://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6923).